# Custom xib not displaying for custom keyboard iOS 8

Tags: ios, keyboard

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard extension for iOS 8. This is my first attempt with iOS development. I just read a few tutorials :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gczzfq6DuHo&app=desktop
http://www.appdesignvault.com/ios-8-custom-keyboard-extension/#a_aid=mdev

I followed the following steps to get started:
1. Created a single view application
2. Created a new target, selected custom keyboard
3. Created a objective c subclass of UIView 
4. Created a xib file (set the class to the one created in 3) (320x216)
5. Typed the following code in keyboardviewcontroller view did load:

```
self.keyboard  = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"<customclassname>" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0]; 
[self.inputView addSubview:self.keyboard];
```

when i run the application and add my keyboard it displays a blank keyboard (nothing is present in the lower 320x216)

Please help me with what I'm doing wrong. Also I'm not able to debug (using breakpoints). I tried the attach to debug process method but I'm not able to see my application listed. I know I'm missing something. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the XIB that you created in step 4.
Replace `<customclassname>` with the name of your XIB file.

In order to debug a keyboard you will need to attach to the process before you run the code.  Type just the name of your keyboard(not the prefixes: use: CoolKeyboard don'tUse: com.MyCompany.CoolKeyboardSettings.CoolKeyboard) into the attach to process- By Process Identifier(PID) or Name.
I find that I need to attach before every debug session.

Comment: Hi seejayare, i have the same name for the uiview class and the xib name and it was not working :( not sure what I'm missing :( I actually did the steps I've mentioned. Regarding debugging I don't find my keyboard listed in that menu of processes. Any help would be much appreciated. I'll try and upload my exact code/project if that would help.

Comment: In your code that you provided you have custom class name in brackets.  You need to put your actual class name in there.  Unless your class name is customclassname.  What is the name of your self.keyboard class? Put that name into the LoadNibNamed:@"" call.  You will not see the keyboard listed in the process identifier list.  You need to press "Attach to process" then "By Process Identifier(PID) or Name..."  In the next dialog it presents, put just the name of your keyboard.  Then run the app, Xcode debugger will wait around until it detects your keyboard running, then it will attach to it.

Comment: Thanks seejayare.. My bad i had by mistake put <customclass in the question wherein i really used the xib name only. i just did what you said regarding he debugger and it worked. The mistake i had done earlier regarding the xib was I had done lazy instantiation in the getter instead of the setter ! :( but all is fine now. Thank you very much !!